# What are all the Mono dependencies required to run all types of C# Windows Forms applications?

Tags: ubuntu, mono

What are the other Mono dependencies besides mono-runtime and libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil required to run C# Windows Forms applications on Ubuntu Linux 16.04?

Does the answer to our question depend on the C# source code for our Windows Forms applications? For example, hellboy81  wrote on gitter im mono, Feb 10 01:46.

> I have Issue with WinForms's TreeView control in Mono under Ubuntu 64
>   Bit 15.10 (Unity) items are not selectable and selection is not
>   visible

Does there exist a package update or new package to fix this problem?

I believe the other Mono dependency, GTK# 2.0 is found by using:

```
strace mono ./Simple.exe
```

If I add the line:

```
using GTK;
```

to `Simple.cs` and compile:

```
mcs -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll -r:System.Drawing.dll -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0 Simple.cs -out:Simple.exe
```

The compiler output is:

```
Package gtk-sharp-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk-sharp-2.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'gtk-sharp-2.0' found.
```

May I ask if gtk-sharp-2.0 is a dependency required for System.Windows.Forms and whether there are any other "Mono" dependencies?

Our architect does not want to consider libgtk2.0-cil-dev as an example of a missing Mono dependency. Instead, he wants to find out what dependencies do we need other than mono-runtime and libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil for List Box, ComboBox, EditBox, buttons, etc.. Do List Box, ComboBox, EditBox, buttons, etc.. require additional Mono dependencies?

Comment: @Moderator, How do I format this question? Thank you.

Comment: Click on the circular question mark at the top right of the editor and the formatting help will be displayed.

Comment: @garethTheRed, Thank you for the nice edit. Would you know of an Linux command we could you use to determine all the  Mono dependencies of a  C# Windows Forms applications?

Comment: Using strace mono ./DataGrid.exe, I just discovered that libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 is a dependency. Should I also install GTK+ 3.0   to run all types of C# Windows Forms applications on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 if it is not already preinstalled?

Comment: The package that provides that library is `libgtk-x11` I believe.

Comment: @garethTheRed, Thank you for your reply. I believe the other Mono dependency, GTK# 2.0 is found by using: 1. strace mono ./Simple.exe 2.mcs -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll -r:System.Drawing.dll -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0 Simple.cs -out:Simple.exe
Package gtk-sharp-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk-sharp-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk-sharp-2.0' found
May I ask if that is correct if I add the line using GTK; to Simple.cs?

Comment: As you can see, comments don't format well.  You can edit your original question to add any useful information though.  Use the `{}` button to format code or output.

Comment: @garethTheRed, I just edited the original question to add more information. Could you briefly look at it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your Mono applications are, just like any other source code, outside of the package management system's control.  Therefore you need to work out yourself which packages you need to install - nothing will tell you.

You have a few options and the simplest of those is to read the developer's documentation.

Failing that, you can (as you have started) run `strace` and see what's missing.  The problem then is working out which package that file belongs to.  In Ubuntu, you can use `apt-file` as follows:

Install and configure it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
$ apt-file update
```

Then find the package with:

```
$ apt-file search gtk-sharp-2.0.pc
```

and it'll tell you that you need to install `libgtk2.0-cil-dev` for this file.

Next run the Mono application again and if need be, `strace` and `apt-file` will help you find the missing files.

Comment: Your answer is great. Our architect does not want  to consider libgtk2.0-cil-dev as an example of a missing Mono dependency. Instead, he wants to find out what dependencies do we need other than mono-runtime and libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil for List Box, ComboBox, EditBox, buttons, etc.. Could you please tell me if List Box, ComboBox, EditBox, buttons, etc.. require additional Mono dependencies?

Comment: I just edited the original question to add more information and an additional question. Could you briefly look at it? Thank you

Comment: The problem now is that this question is moving from a Linux admin question to a developer question, which may well be better suited to http://stackoverflow.com/.  I don't know how much help you'll get over there as your question is quite vague.  The 'etc' at the end makes it quite an open ended one.  Which packages you'll require really depends on what 'etc' is.

Comment: @garethTherRed, Thank you for your comment. I will ask our architect what is meant by "etc" and try to connect with you given Britain and US East Coast time difference.